# Migrate SVN directory from standard to SSH

Tags: svn, ssh

I have an SVN repo that I want to change to work over SSH, but don't want to checkout again. I have added the appropriate tunnels, but when I go to checkout, it still goes over HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `svn switch --relocate old-url new-url .` to convert the default access URL.

Answer (score 0):

From within the working directory of your checked out repository:

`svn switch svn+ssh://some.server/path/to/repo .`

See [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html).

Comment: typo in the URL, should be `svn+ssh`